# Paint на Swing. Почему NPE?

Tags: java, swing, button, action

Делаю рисовалку на Swing, хочу задать три кнопки которые меняли бы толщину линии, которая будет рисоваться. Наверное, я что-то не так делаю с `addActionListener`. Выбивает NOP на тех вещах, где будет использоваться 
`gg.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));`:

```
public class PPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener
{   
    int x;
    int y;
     Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
    public PPanel() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);


        btn1.addActionListener(this);

        btn5.addActionListener(this);
        btn10.addActionListener(this);
        add(btn10);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == btn10)
        {
            gg.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        }
    }
    JButton btn1 = new JButton();

    JButton btn5 = new JButton();
    JButton btn10 = new JButton();

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {

        gg.drawOval(e.getX(), e.getY(), 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //setBackground(Color.black);
        //repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        //setBackground(Color.white);
        //repaint();        
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
        gg.setColor(Color.green);
        gg.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int firstX = e.getX();
        int firstY = e.getY();
        gg.drawLine(firstX, firstY, e.getX(), e.getY());

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Graphics` и `Graphics2D` - объекты отрисованного вида компонента. Они создаются заново при каждой новой отрисовке.

Поскольку `Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();` выполняется в момент инициализации объекта, когда компонент еще не нарисован (и не может быть нарисован), в `gg` заносится `null`. Отсюда и NPE.

[В документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) описан типичный метод реализации такой рисовалки. Если коротко, объект графики получаем в переопределенном методе `paintComponent`, там и работаем.